# Adding Column to pandas DataFrame in Vectorized way conditioning on other column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, vectorization

I have a pandas dataframe `df`

```
>>> df
           a  b  c  
0          1  1  0             
1          1 -1  1                    
2          1  0  0
```

Now I want to add a new column df['e'] conditioning on column `a` and `b`. I would like to create the new column in vectorized manner.

For now, I am doing like the following:

```
df["e"] = [-1 if (df['a'] == 1 and df['b'] == 1) else 1]
```

which should output:

```
>>> df
               a  b  c  e 
    0          1  1  0 -1          
    1          1 -1  1  1                  
    2          1  0  0  1
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/hmishfaq/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 917, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What am I doing wrong and what's the correct way of vectorizing here?

PS: The original dataframe I need to use is really big and thus for-loop takes forever to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use very fast [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['e'] = np.where((df['a'] == 1) & (df['b'] == 1), -1, 1)
print (df)
   a  b  c  e
0  1  1  0 -1
1  1 -1  1  1
2  1  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error stems from the fact that you're using `and`, instead of `&`. Switch to the latter and your error will go away.

Solution:

```
df["e"] = [-1 if (df['a'] == 1 & df['b'] == 1) else 1]
```